# Elastic search kibana : 404 error in genearted pdf report

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-cloud

I am using elastic cloud on V7.16.2. I am trying to generate a PDF report out of elastic search Kibana dashboard. I am able to queue the report but in the PDF report is see below text only.

```
{statusCode: 404, error: "Not Found", message: "Not Found"}
```

Report generation was working fine for the same dashboard and using the same user few days back. I have verified the permissions and it has "reporting" role attached to the user.

Few observations

1. Other users with exactly same permissions are able to generate report for the same dashboard.
2. The user is able to generate PDF report on different dashboard.

I checked if the user has some limitation on number of reports on particular dashboard, But it don't see any such property for elastic cloud.

any idea what's wrong here?

PS: I have also posted same problem on elastic cloud community but creating here to get more reach-ability. You can find that [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/404-on-pdf-report/295606)